# Set a particular Office file to NOT autorecover

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

I am working on a very large Excel workbook as well as other workbooks. The data on the very large workbook should be read-only anyway (but I would still need to edit it to filter and such) so I want to turn autorecover off for that particular file, but leave it on for other files. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

From here: http://ccm.net/faq/34034-excel-disable-the-autorecover-feature-for-a-specific-workbook

1. Open the notebook you wish to disable Autorecover on.
2. Go to **File** > **Options**.
3. In the **Save** section, under **Autorecover exceptions for:**  click **Disabled Autorecover for this workbook only**